# Is 301 or 302 used for country forwarding?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, 302-redirect, technical-seo

I want to make country redirects for my site and I am not sure which redirect type is used.

Step 1: First, we enter our website.

Step 1 URL: `https://example.com`

Step 2: Our website directs us to whichever country we are in.

Step 2 URL: `https://example.com/en`

My question is, should step 1 here be a 301 redirect or a 302 redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server-side 302**

Dynamic serving is also a viable option here.

Remember to include the `x-default rel-alternate-hreflang` directive - so both the homepage and the generic page if the generic page is a redirect page that's inaccessible to users.

When doing this I recommend including *some* method to allow users to switch to a local version or different language version. Perhaps a dropdown or other UI element.

[Further reading](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your)

Comment: Thanks again for the resource and your reply. :)